# dont know why '\n' is not working for next line

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-step

I am using '/n' in below way

```
public String appComment{get;set;}
for(Processinstancehistory p:listp)
{
appComment=appComment +'\n'+ p.Comments+'\n';
}
```

I am getting result in one line . I need every approver comment in separate line. how can I achieve it

Comment: where are you displaying this concatenated comment?

Comment: in an email template. which is having a table . The column Approval comments  fetches this value

Comment: try using `<br/>`

Comment: i dont think <br/> will work inside apex class

Comment: You cannot use apex class in any of the email templates text/custom/visualforce email templates. Unless you mean, you want to send an email via apex?

Comment: From your previous answer, I get the feeling you are using an HTML email template. If you use a Visualforce email template you could include full iteration of the comments for the history values and therefore apply template-level formatting markup to nicely arrange the text. If you use HTML be aware that whitespace (including carriage returns) get "normalized" into single spaces when the HTML is rendered. Final point - did you try escaping the backslash with another backslash?

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the reply . I tried escaping the backslash with another backslash but still its not working

Comment: @compski thanks for the reply . On an approval submission I am triggering an email . That mail template has a controller which uses above lines of code to fetch approver comments

Comment: which email template are you displaying this concatenated comment in? Text/Custom/ HTML/Visualforce?

Comment: @user75937 you did not consider my other points (partially echoed by compski above).

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I was bored so I wrote out what I hope is a pretty detailed code sample. This is as far as I'm willing to go however.

If you're using Visualforce for your email template per your comments, you want to do something like this:

```
public List<String> appComments {get; set;}
```

Then in the constructor:

```
this.appComments = new List<String>();
```

Then somewhere else in your code where you are currently running your loop:

```
for(Processinstancehistory p:listp) {
    appComments.add(p.Comments);
}
```

Then in your VF template

```
<apex:repeat value="{!appComments}" var="comment"> 
<!-- or apex:dataTable or some other iteration component -->
    <apex:outputText value="{!comment}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do a table I wouldn't even bother creating a list of strings. Instead you could use your list of records:

```
public Id recordId {get; private set;}
public Case record {get; private set;} // just a sample, youll use what ever object you want
public Map<Id, List<ProcessInstanceHistory>> histories {get; private set;}

// Assuming you're using a custom controller
public customControllerConstructor() {
    Id recordId;

    try {
        recordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParamters().get('recordId');
        init();
        // Never use Id as a custom parameter name, this is a reserved param for sfdc
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // If the Id is not valid, you may get an error
        // handle your error here
    }


}

// If you're using an extention
public customControllerConstructor(ApexPages.standardController stdCon) {
    this.recordId = stdCon.getRecordId();
    init();
}

public void init() {
    if (this.recordId != null) {
        this.record = [
            SELECT Id, Fields..., (
                SELECT Id, Fields...
                FROM ProcessInstances
            )
            FROM Case
            WHERE Id = :
        ];

        histories = new Map<Id, List<ProcessInstanceHistory>>();

        for (Processinstancehistory history : [
            SELECT Id, Comments, Actor.Name
            FROM Processinstancehistory
            WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN :this.record.ProcessInstances
        ]) {
            if (!this.histories.get(history.ProcessInstanceId) == null) {
                // Contains key will tell you if the key exists but not if the list
                // is initialized so we use .get == null instead
                this.histories.put(history.ProcessInstanceId, new List<Processinstancehistory>());
            }

            this.histories.get(history.ProcessInstanceId).add(history);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your VF Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!record.ProcessInstances}" var="instance">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!histories[instance.id]}" var="history">
        <apex:column value="{!history.Actor.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!history.comments}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:repeat>
```